# Chrome Disk Cache Size Not Effective in Kiosk Mode or Incognito Session for High-Resolution Media in Web Application

Tags: google-chrome, kiosk-mode, incognito-mode

I'm developing a public-facing web application that serves high-resolution photos and videos, sometimes exceeding 80MB in size. The application runs in kiosk mode, which essentially opens it in an incognito session with new tab and window functionalities disabled.

When rendering these large media files, the browser continually downloads them, resulting in excessive data consumption. To mitigate this, I attempted to adjust the disk cache size using the command:

```
google-chrome --disk-cache-size=900000000 --incognito
```

However, I noticed that this setting only seems to work in the normal browsing mode, and it doesn't have any effect when the browser is opened in kiosk mode or incognito.

I'm seeking advice on how to effectively manage disk cache size in Chrome when running a web application in kiosk mode or incognito session. Any insights or alternative approaches to optimize resource consumption would be greatly appreciated.